# i get error when i try to upload a file?

Tags: php, html, file, upload, undefined-index

I keep getting  an error:**Notice**:  Undefined index:  on line **35**

line 35:

```
 $handle = new Upload($_FILES['my_field']);
```

this is my input field

```
 <input type="file" size="32" name="my_field" value="" />
```

I do not understand this error, thanks!!!

EDIT:

```
 <form name="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="actions/upload.php" />
 <p><input type="file" size="32" name="my_field" value="" /></p>
 <p class="button"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="image" />
 <br>
 <input style="margin-left:224px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
```

Comment: Can you show the full HTML form?

Comment: yeh let me update it thanks!!

Comment: Looks like the file isnt actually getting uploaded
you should check to see if it uploaded successfully first
is_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_filed']['tmp_name'])
or
isset($_FILES['my_field']) 
before acting on them

Comment: We need the entire HTML form and the library you are using. I am assuming that you are using one because of the Upload class.

Comment: Strange. Can you do a `print_r($_FILES)`?

Comment: yeh i am using a class!! its a long file!!! lol

Comment: @patrick the file hasnt been uploaded, i just checked!!

Comment: @pekka it gives me `array()` that's it :))

Comment: Thai's answer should help you, if not let us know

Comment: You are 100% sure that there is no other element named `my_field` in the form?

Comment: maybe its something with the server, that cnt deal with the file

Comment: by the way im sending through an ajax request, i forgot to mention!!!

Comment: @getaway File uploads don't work with Ajax requests

Comment: You cant send files through ajax lol pekka beat me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The OP is doing an Ajax request - well that obviously can't work with a File upload.

**Old answer:**

I think I found it.

Look closely at this tag:

```
 <form name="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
 action="actions/upload.php" />
```

the closing `/>` *closes the form.* Everything that comes afterwards, is not inside that form - it's inside a new one that the browser probably generates to deal with the broken markup. That new form is not `enctype=multipart/form-data`.

Comment: thats true it works, so how can i send a file thorough an ajax request!!! +1 from me ive seen examples of people uploading photos through jquery

Answer (score 2):

Did you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form element?

This seems to be the only reason that the the key `my_field` isn't set on `$_FILES`.

Edit: If your file is bigger than [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), you also get an empty `$_FILES` array.

See also: [Apache/PHP: $_FILES Array mysteriously empty](http://getluky.net/2004/10/04/apachephp-_files-array-mysteriously-empty/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload WITH an ajax submission you can use an IFRAME with the upload part in there.

1. Send ajax form submission
2. Using javascript trigger submit() on the upload form in the IFRAME
3. Have the returning page in the iframe trigger a javascript complete response function in the main page

A bit complicated but would work. You would need some mechanism to tie them together, for instance if you are submiting info about the image, have step 1 return the id of the database row where that info is stored so that the IFRAME upload form can submit that id so it knows where to store the picture.